# java stream is making weird things to generate csv file in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-stream, export-to-csv

I'm processing a csv file through my springboot app, the file is to download it, in my case I use streams but there is a problem what I don't know what's wrong in my code because some rows is complete with the columns but next row only write some columns and leftover columns are write below as if were a new row. I hope you understand what I mean. I hope you give a hand, thank you in advance.

This code below is the controller

```
.....
@RequestMapping(value="/stream/csv/{grupo}/{iduser}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void generateCSVUsingStream(@PathVariable("grupo") String grupo,
            @PathVariable("iduser") String userId,HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/csv");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+userId+"_Reporte_PayCash"+grupo.replaceAll("\\s", "")+".csv");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        try (Stream<ReportePayCashDTO> streamPaycashdatos = capaDatosDao.ReportePayCashStream(userId, grupo);PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();) {
            //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.write(String.join(",", "Cuenta" , "Referencia", "Referencia_paycash","Distrito","Plaza","Cartera"));
            out.write("\n");
            streamPaycashdatos.forEach(streamdato -> {
                
        out.write(streamdato.getAccount()+","+streamdato.getReferencia()+","+streamdato.getReferenciapaycash()
            +","+streamdato.getCartera()+","+streamdato.getState()+","+streamdato.getCity());
                out.append("\r\n");
                
            });
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            streamPaycashdatos.close();
        } catch (IOException ix) {
            throw new RuntimeException("There is an error while downloading file", ix);
        }
}
```

The method on DAO is this

```
...
@Override
public Stream<ReportePayCashDTO> ReportePayCashStream(String userId, String grupo) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Stream<ReportePayCashDTO > stream = null ;
String query ="";
//more code
try {
            
            stream = getJdbcTemplate().queryForStream(query, (rs, rowNum) -> {
 return new ReportePayCashDTO(Utils.valnull(rs.getString("account")), 
                        Utils.valnull(rs.getString("reference")),
                        Utils.valnull(rs.getString("referencepaycash")),
                        Utils.valnull(rs.getString("state")),
                        Utils.valnull(rs.getString("city")),
                        Utils.valnull(rs.getString("cartera"))
                        );
            });
}catch(Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        
        return stream;
}
```

Example: This is what I hoped will write into csv file

```
55xxxxx02,88xxxx153,1170050202662,TAMAULIPAS,TAMPICO,AmericanExpre
58xxxxx25,88xxx899,1170050202662,TAMAULIPAS,TAMPICO,AmericanClasic
```

but some rows was written like this

```
55xxxxx02,88xxxx153,1170050202662
,TAMAULIPAS,TAMPICO,AmericanExpre
58xxxxx25,88xxx899,1170050202662
,TAMAULIPAS,TAMPICO,AmericanClasic
```

Comment: First of all, clean up this code. When you use `try(…)`, there is no reason to perform additional manual `close()` calls. And calling `flush()` before `close()` never made sense, as `close()` implies `flush()`. Then, *be consistent*. When you use `String.join(",", …)` for the header, why don’t you use it for the other rows as well? And why are you using sometimes `\n` and sometimes `\r\n`? But since you have a `PrintWriter`, you can use `println` to write a line with line break in one call.

Comment: In summary, just `try(Stream<ReportePayCashDTO> streamPaycashdatos = capaDatosDao.ReportePayCashStream(userId, grupo);PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) { out.println(String.join(",", "Cuenta" , "Referencia", "Referencia_paycash", "Distrito", "Plaza", "Cartera")); streamPaycashdatos.forEach(obj -> out.println(String.join(",", obj.getAccount(), obj.getReferencia(), obj.getReferenciapaycash(), obj.getCartera(), obj.getState(), obj.getCity())));
} catch (IOException ix) { ...  }`. When your issue is a concurrency problem, this simplification will already fix it. Otherwise, update question…

Comment: Thank you @Holger, I just cleaning my code as you commented me, and I realized that the problem was a new line character into text that is brought from database. Therefore the issue was resolved.